# D3 v4 force graph with images as nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Having problems using images as nodes in a force-directed graph. Everything I've looked at so far seems to be v3 code and I haven't been able to get any images at all so far, whether using xlink:href or svg:image or both.

What's the right way to use an img as a node with v4?

Here's what I'm trying, and a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asparism/s6uzfre3/).

As you can see in the CSS, I'm trying to get images from a spritesheet for each node.

```
var defs = d3.append("svg:defs");

defs.append("svg:pattern")
      .attr("width", 48)
      .attr("height", 48)
      //.attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
      .append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href", "http://placekitten.com/g/48/48")
      .attr("width", 48)
      .attr("height", 48)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("y", 0);


var nodesDrawn = svg
.selectAll("node")
.data(nodesData)
.enter()
.append("g")
//.append("xhtml:i")
.append('circle')
.attr('r', 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems so far:

1. There is no `d3.append` in D3. You probably meant `svg.append`.
2. Set the width and the height of the `<pattern>` to 1.
3. Set an ID to the `<pattern>` and use that to fill the circles.

Here are the code with that changes (I'm increasing the circles' radii, so you can better see the image): https://jsfiddle.net/ppk23hnz/

By the way, none of those changes are related to D3 version: they are the same in v3.x and v4.x.

PS: Don't mix jQuery and D3. you don't need that (and it's quite disturbing).

Comment: Why did you change the width and height of the pattern to 1? And why does it need an ID in order to fill the circles? I had heard not to mix the two but hadn't run into any problems yet :)